# Why sqlite strftime function doen't return any rows.?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

Hi there i have been working on an sqlite project for about a month now i have store my dates in the format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" (i.e. **25-03-2019 18:36:59 PM** )now i want to get records from-to dates.

i have tried using this strftime function with the same format but zero rows are returned.
My query looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM products as SM WHERE SM.date BETWEEN strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', '24-03-2019 12:00:00 AM') AND strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', '26-03-2019 12:00:00 AM')"
```

Here is my c# code for you guys to look at

```
using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionStringManual()))
                {
                    using (SQLiteDataAdapter adapter  = new SQLiteDataAdapter (query,con))
                    {
                        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToDate", dttoDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
                        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromDate", dtfromDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
                        adapter.Fill(dtbl);
                    }
                }
```

it works when i remove the Where clause. I don't know how to make it work so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The date and time functions return null when given a string that's not in one of the formats they can handle. See the list of supported formats here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: try removing the ` AM` from the date string. if that doesn't work, try changing to `strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '2019-03-24')`

Comment: @Shawn Thanks already looked into it and found the solution, but the thing is i have over 6000 records and i don't want to change date for each them in the format that sqlite handles.

Comment: @Matt.G thank you for the suggestion but already tried that, doesn't work.

Comment: Another problem with the format you're using is that the strings can't be meaningfully ordered. `'24-03-2019 ...'`compares as less than `'25-03-2018 ...'` for example.

Comment: @Shawn so what are you suggesting.?

Comment: I suggest storing your timestamps in one of the formats accepted by the date and time functions.

Comment: @Shawn seems like i have no choice